# How to use Context Provider and Consumer in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

**DataProvider.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {ProjectFirestore} from '../Config/Firebase';

const DataContext = React.createContext();

class DataProvider extends Component {

  state = {
    orderHistory: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUserOrderHistory();
  }

  fetchUserOrderHistory = ()=>{
    let orderHistory = [];
    let orderRef = ProjectFirestore.collection("global-orders");
    let query = orderRef.where('user_id', '==', 'someId')
        query.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                orderHistory.push({
                  id    : doc.id,
                  itemprice : doc.data().itemprice,
                });
            });

            this.setState(() => {
              return { orderHistory };
            });
        });
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <DataContext.Provider
        value={
          {...this.state}
        }
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </DataContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

const DataConsumer = DataContext.Consumer;

export { DataProvider , DataConsumer };
```

**OrderHistory.js**

```
import { DataConsumer } from "../contexts/DataProvider.js";

export default function OrderHistory() {

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
        <DataConsumer>
          {
            value => {
              return value.orderHistory.map( (item) =>{
                return
                (
                  <div>
                    {item.deliverycharge}
                );
              });
            }
          }
        </DataConsumer>
      </div>
      <Footer/>
    </>
  );


}
```

> Error : Cannot read property 'orderHistory' of undefined

The component **DataProvider** fetches the data from firebase firestore and updates the state with the `return {orderHistory}`. I want to be able to use the `orderHistory: []` value in the **orderHistory** component. The problem  is that the **value** in ***'orderHistory.js'*** passed by the `<DataConsumer>` is always null.  I do not want alternatives, I just need help figuring out what is wrong with this specific code.

Comment: What's the value of `this.state` in `DataProvider`? Is the value you receive in the child component still `null` if you hardcode in a value in `DataContext.Provider`? Maybe a stupid question, but there's no stupid questions in debugging.

Comment: I harcoded the orderHistory  and i still get value.orderHistory 'undefined' error

Comment: OK i got it , I forgot to use the DataProvider in the  App.js to be consumed. Damn.

Comment: Huzzah! It's always something like that, isn't it? Glad you're up and running.

Comment: yeah man . I'm glad I can move on now :) The reason i asked for no alternatives is that i like how elegant this is and don't wat to use other ways. I have lot of other code in the provider component that delivers all required data for the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to also import the **DataProvider** in the `./App.js` to provide the data to be consumed by the components it encapsulates within the `<DataProvider> ... </DataProvider>`.

```
import { DataProvider } from './contexts/DataProvider.js'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
      <AuthProvider>
        <DataProvider>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route path='/history' component={OrderHistory}/>
          </Switch>
        </DataProvider>
        </AuthProvider>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be its own component beneath the consumer:

```js
{
            value => {
              return value.orderHistory.map( (item) =>{
                return
                (
                  <div>
                    {item.deliverycharge}
                );
              });
            }
          }
```

And you need to write it like this instead:

```js
class MyComponent extends Component {
render() {
  
  return (
    // Use "this.context" instead of "value"
    this.context.orderHistory.map( (item) =>{
      return
      (
        <div>
          {item.deliverycharge}
        </div>
      );
    });
  )
}

MyComponent.contextType = DataContext; // Attaches the context to the component
```

Comment: Appreciate the help. I was looking for an answer specific to the code I posted in my question. Do you see anything wrong with that code because i've used similiar code in other projects and somehow this isn't working and i'm not able to figure out why.

Comment: If you can do what you've written there, that's news to me. Maybe you can though. My understanding is you need to attach the context either as I've shown, or via the `useContext()` hook for functional components.

Comment: const DataConsumer = DataContext.Consumer;
export { DataProvider , DataConsumer };

i've imported the { DataConsumer }  in the orher component to use the 'value'. I'v e done it in another project in the past but somehow its not working . I'm probably missing something .